# Calculating animation time Qt

Tags: c++, qt, animation

First of, I'm fairly new to Qt. I did look for the answer but didn't find anything similar to my problem. I am using a timer that timeouts every 50ms and a

```
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),scene,SLOT(advance()));
```

to animate a circling rectangle(my own class that paints the rectangle and changes its coordinates every time `advance` is called) until it does a full circle on a `QGraphicsView`.

Is there any way to measure the time it takes the animation to finish? Basically I'm pushing the button, the animation starts, the rectangle finishes the circle and I need to output the time it took it to do so. I know I can use QTime to calculate the time but I don't understand where the to put it because it is using the signal-slot mechanism and a timer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly and you are only trying to measure the time it took for you to draw the animation, and not the *actual* time it took to draw the animation, then your task is quite simple.

If the timer times out every 50 ms, then if you count the number of steps it took for you to draw the animations, and multiply that by 50ms, you have the complete time.

If your advance() function steps every time by a fixed amount of radians, then you don't need to calculate anything. You know beforehand how much time will it take. It can be easily calculated as such:

```
t = StepTime * (2 * pi) / StepAngle
```

if step angle is in radians, or alternatively

```
t = StepTime * (360)/StepAngle
```

if step angle is in degrees.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I do actually need the actual time since I'm trying to compare its performance on different PC's(just part of something I was asked to do for an assignment). As far as I understand the times are going to be really close because of the method I chose to implement the animation(I'm guessing there are better ways of doing it for my case but this one seemed to be the easiest) but I'm not even sure how I can get those times.